# ¿Se puede Deserializar y mapear un Json sin modelo en C#?

Tags: c#, json

Lo que pasa es que tengo un requerimiento, tengo un Json pero nesecito capturar el valor, pero tengo que hacerlo sin usar un Model, he visto ejemplos pero todos manejan models.

¿es posible deserializar sin un model?

De momento lo estoy haciendo asi:

**Paso 1:**

Creo el Json desde PostMan

```
{
   "CAMPO_EN_LA_TABLA": "valor que quiero capturar"
}
```

**Paso 2:**

Cree un modelo Private en la clase, para poder serializar:

```
private class Parametros
{
    [Key]
    public int Empid { get; set; }

    public string Codigo { get; set; }

    [Column(TypeName = "sql_variant")]
    public object Valor { get; set; }
}
```

**Paso 3:**

Lo deserializo asi en un Dictionary:

```
var listParametros = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Parametros>(valor.ToString());
```

**Paso 4:**

Y ya lo ultimo es capturar el valor y guardarlo en algun parametro:

```
object ValorCapturado = listParametros.Valor;
Console.WriteLine("Este es el valor impreso: " + listParametros.Valor);
```

Como ven se como deserializar, pero en los requerimientos me piden hacerlo sin el Model, pero no se como mapearlo asi

Comment: pero el json que muestras envias desde postman no tiene nada que ver con la clase Parametros que estas definiendo, no le veo ninguna relacion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si necesitas deserializar de forma generica, puedes usar el `JObject`

[Parsing JSON Object using JObject.Parse](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/ParseJsonObject.htm)

```
string json = @"{
  CPU: 'Intel',
  Drives: [
    'DVD read/writer',
    '500 gigabyte hard drive'
  ]
}";

JObject o = JObject.Parse(json);
```

se puede deserializar sin un objeto

[Using JSON.NET for dynamic JSON parsing](https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2012/Aug/30/Using-JSONNET-for-dynamic-JSON-parsing)

analiza el titulo "Importing JSON with JObject.Parse() and JArray.Parse()"
pero basicamente define

```
var jsonString = @"{""Name"":""Rick"",""Company"":""West Wind"",
                    ""Entered"":""2012-03-16T00:03:33.245-10:00""}";

dynamic json = JValue.Parse(jsonString);

string name = json.Name;
string company = json.Company;
DateTime entered = json.Entered;
```

al usar `dynamic` no tendrias problema en deserializar el json sin una clase

Si usas el JObject puedes acceder a los nodos

[Parse JSON object in C# with different value types](https://gist.github.com/ryanwi/6191055)

```
string sampleJson = "{\"results\":[" +
    "{\"employeename\":\"name1\",\"employeesupervisor\":\"supervisor1\"}," +
    "{\"employeename\":\"name2\",\"employeesupervisor\":\"supervisor1\"}," +
    "{\"employeename\":\"name3\",\"employeesupervisor\":[\"supervisor1\",\"supervisor2\"]}" +
    "]}";

// Parse JSON into dynamic object, convenient!
JObject results = JObject.Parse(sampleJson);

// Process each employee
foreach (var result in results["results"])
{
    // this can be a string or null
    string employeeName = (string)result["employeename"];

  //resto codigo
```

En resumen podrias usar el JObject o dynamic para deserializar sin una clase con la cual mapear el json

Answer (score 0):

Prueba hacer lo siguiente:

```
dynamic d = JObject.Parse("{number:1000, str:'string', array: [1,2,3,4,5,6]}");

Console.WriteLine(d.number);
Console.WriteLine(d.str);
Console.WriteLine(d.array.Count);
```

obtenemos un objeto dinámico sin necesidad de usar un modelo. Espero que te sirva, Saludos!

[Documentación](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/LINQtoJSON.htm)

Answer (score 0):

Un modo de hacer lo que buscas, es usando el tipo [dynamic](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/dynamic) y [JsonConvert.DeserializeAnonymousType Method (String, T)](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonConvert_DeserializeAnonymousType__1.htm)

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
//Creo un string con un JSON de ejemplo
string JsonDeEjemplo = "[{'CAMPO_EN_LA_TABLA': 'valor que quiero capturar'}, {'CAMPO_EN_LA_TABLA': 'segundo valor que quiero capturar'}, {'CAMPO_EN_LA_TABLA': 'tercer valor que quiero capturar'}]";            
//Uso DeserializeAnonymouseType para obtener un List<dynamic> con el contenido deserializado
var ListaDinamica = JsonConvert.DeserializeAnonymousType<List<dynamic>>(JsonDeEjemplo,null);
//Por cada variable dynamic en ListaDinamica..
foreach(var Dyn in ListaDinamica)
{
    //Muestro la propiedad CAMPO_EN_LA_TABLA
    Console.WriteLine(Dyn.CAMPO_EN_LA_TABLA);
}
```

Te dejo un [dotnetfiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/KT1eEP) del ejemplo funcionando